# ImageButton title tag

Tags: asp.net, imagebutton

On an ImageButton using the AlternateText attribute renders an alt tag to the browser.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imagebuttonStuff" runat="server" OnClick="imagebuttonStuff_Click" AlternateText="Make Stuff Happen" ImageUrl="/images/icons/stuff.png" />

<input type="image" name="imagebuttonStuff" id="imagebuttonStuff" src="/images/icons/stuff.png" alt="Make Stuff Happen" />
```

How do I render a title tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ToolTip="this is the title"
```

Comment: Ha, of course! I went to the bother of creating the jQuery below and thought surely there has to be an easier way?

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("input").each(function(i) {
                    if (this.alt != '')
                        $(this).attr("title", $(this).attr("alt"))
                });
        });
    </script>