# imagebutton alternative text doesn't appear in chrome

Tags: asp.net, imagebutton

image button alternative text doesn't appear in chrome browser this is html button code

```
<div class="bookoffer">
                            <table class="headertable" style="padding-bottom: 0px; height: 100%;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="bookbt">
                                        <asp:ImageButton   AlternateText="Book" CssClass="bookstyle" ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OfferID") %>' OnCommand="ImageButton1_Command" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

why alternative text doesn't appear ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Tooltip property to get Firefox and Chrome to show an alt:

ToolTip="this is the title"

[ImageButton title tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1940087/imagebutton-title-tag)